# How can you optimize this code to make it smaller?

Tags: python

I have a code to check statistics, and I am terribly annoyed by its unpleasant appearance. I also have a list with language codes and a list with base collections. I tried to do something like this:

```
a = ""
for i in iso:
   a += i
```

but this option does not fit a bit, have any ideas how to make it smaller?

```
iso = ["ru", "uk", "en", "de", "es", "fr", "it", "fa", "ar", "ko"]
collections = [files, groups, users, blocked]


    statistic.format(
        await files.count_documents({}),
        await groups.count_documents({}),
        await users.count_documents({}),
        await blocked.count_documents({}),
        await count_lang("ru"), await count_lang("uk"),
        await count_lang("en"), await count_lang("de"),
        await count_lang("es"), await count_lang("fr"),
        await count_lang("it"), await count_lang("fa"),
        await count_lang("ar"), await count_lang("ko")))
```

Sorry for the stupid question, I am new to python and I already tried to reduce it but failed

Comment: As this is fully working code that you want to improve, I think you would be better posting it on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ make sure you read the posting guidelines there first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change your `"for"` statement:

```
count_lang_arr = []
for i in iso:
   a = await count_lang(i)
   count_lang_arr.append(a)
```

To print the results you can just use the `print` statement

```
print(count_lang_arr)
```